# Nodemailer causing build failures in Vercel with Qwik app

Tags: vercel, qwik, qwikjs

I'm running into an issue deploying my Qwik app to Vercel. Whenever nodemailer is imported, it causes the build to fail with this error:

````
[commonjs--resolver] Cannot bundle Node.js built-in "events" imported from "node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js". Consider disabling ssr.noExternal or remove the built-in dependency.```


I've tried:

Upgrading nodemailer to the latest version
Adding ssr.noExternal to my vite config
Removing nodemailer entirely and the build succeeds

But I need to keep nodemailer for sending emails. How can I resolve this conflict between nodemailer and Vercel/Qwik?

My packages:

Qwik 1.2.6
Nodemailer 6.9.4
Vercel CLI 29.1.1
Node v18.17.1.
````

Comment: Isn't qwik a frontend framework while nodemailer is a backend emailing library for node js? How does something in your backend server crash your frontend app?

Comment: Well, as strange as that might sound, I will be glad to share link to my github repo so that you take a look at my code and maybe advise me accordingly.

Comment: Sure thing, I am interested.

Comment: Vercel is an edge platform which do not support nodejs packages you have to use those pkgs that are web standared and supported by vercel. This apply to most of the edge platform like Netlify etc..